# Core Data: Deletion of Entity deletes from a separate instance

Tags: swift, core-data, entity-relationship

Here's the core data schema:

Program --->> Weeks --->> Days --->> Exercises

I have a problem that when I create a few Weeks within a Program, then create another Program with a few Weeks, deleting a week from one Program will delete from the other Program's Weeks. This also happens within the Days and Exercises.

Maybe my delete function is wrong?

For example:

*Program 1*

1. Week One
2. Week Two
3. Week Three

*Program 2*

1. Week One A
2. Week Two A
3. Week Three A

Deleting Week Two A from Program 2 will delete Week Two from Program 1 and so on..

**WeekViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class WeekViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let manager = PersistenceController.shared
    @Published var weeks: [WeekEntity] = []
    
    init() {
        getWeeks()
    }
    
    func getWeeks() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<WeekEntity>(entityName: "WeekEntity")
        
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        do {
            weeks = try manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching weeks! \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addWeek(name: String, program: ProgramEntity) {
        let newWeek = WeekEntity(context: manager.container.viewContext)
        newWeek.name = name
        newWeek.programs = program
        save()
    }
    
    func deleteWeeks(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let week = weeks[index]
            manager.context.delete(week)
        }
        save()
        getWeeks()
    }
    
    // moveWeek?
    
    func save() {
        manager.save()
    }
}
```

**WeekListView**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct WeekListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var weekViewModel: WeekViewModel
    
    var program: ProgramEntity
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let mulWeeks = program.multipleWeeks?.array as? [WeekEntity] {
                ForEach(mulWeeks, id: \.self) { week in
                    ZStack {
                        Text(week.name ?? "")
                            .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .light, design:.default))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("lightblue"))
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 350, height: 60, alignment: .leading)
                            //.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20).stroke(Color("lightblue"), lineWidth: 2))
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: DayView(week: week)) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                        .opacity(0.0)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: weekViewModel.deleteWeeks)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WeekListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let context = PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
        let program = ProgramEntity(context: context)
        program.name = "Program 2"
        return WeekListView(program: program)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
            
            .environmentObject(WeekViewModel())
    }
}
```

*If needed*

**ProgramsViewModel**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class ProgramsViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let manager = PersistenceController.shared
    @Published var programs: [ProgramEntity] = []
    
    
    init() {
        getPrograms()
    }
    
    func getPrograms() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ProgramEntity>(entityName: "ProgramEntity")
        //let date = NSDate()
        
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        do {
            programs = try manager.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching programs! \(error)")
        }
        
    }
    
    func addProgram(name: String, weeks: Int64, days: Int64) {
        let newProgram = ProgramEntity(context: manager.container.viewContext)
        newProgram.name = name
        newProgram.weeks = weeks
        newProgram.days = days
        save()
    }
    
    
    
    func deletePrograms(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for index in offsets {
            let program = programs[index]
            manager.context.delete(program)
        }
        save()
        getPrograms()
    }
    
    func moveProgram(from: IndexSet, to: Int) {
        programs.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
        save()
    }
    
    func save() {
        manager.save()
    }
    
    func addWeekProgram(week: WeekEntity) {
        let newWeek = ProgramEntity(context: manager.container.viewContext)
        newWeek.addToMultipleWeeks(week)
        
    }

}
```

**ProgramsListView**

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ProgramListView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @EnvironmentObject var programsViewModel: ProgramsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        workingVStack
        
    }
}

struct ProgramListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProgramListView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
            .environmentObject(ProgramsViewModel())

    }
}

extension ProgramListView {
    
    private var workingVStack: some View {
        ForEach(programsViewModel.programs, id: \.self) { program in
            ZStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(program.name ?? "")
                                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .light, design: .default))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color("lightblue"))
                                
                            }
                            HStack {
                                Text("Weeks:")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                Text("\(program.weeks)")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Days:")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                Text("\(program.days)")
                            }
                            .frame(width: 300)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: WeekView(program: program)) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .opacity(0.0)
            }
        }
        .onDelete(perform: programsViewModel.deletePrograms)
        .onMove(perform: programsViewModel.moveProgram)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do research on deletion rules for databases.

Comment: I think your data model is wrong, when you save a program the weeks you set is not an array of WeekEntity but an Int64?. You should research using and setting up relationships and inverse relationships because you are definitely doing something strange when it comes to entity relationships

Comment: That Weeks: Int 64 is just for UI, I'm probably gonna get rid of that. The relationship is called multipleWeeks: Week Entity as you can see in the WeekListView. Also everything saves fine, its just the deletion that I'm having trouble with.